# How to get an ArrayList out of a Field object in Java for Unit test

Tags: java, arraylist, junit, field

I am trying to unit test a setter method in Java. I'm working in android studio and the function I want to test loads data from the resources file and populates it in 4 ArrayLists.

In my test I am trying to use reflection with field objects the code looks like this:

```
dataSource.loadData();

    final Field[] fields = new Field[4];
    fields[0] = dataSource.getClass().getDeclaredField("images");
    fields[1] = dataSource.getClass().getDeclaredField("categories");
    fields[2] = dataSource.getClass().getDeclaredField("descriptions");
    fields[3] = dataSource.getClass().getDeclaredField("categoryDescriptions");

    fields[0].setAccessible(true);
    fields[1].setAccessible(true);
    fields[2].setAccessible(true);
    fields[3].setAccessible(true);

    assertTrue("Images is empty", fields[0].get(dataSource).isEmpty() ==false);
```

dataSource is an object of the class I am testing. Basically the class has 4 ArrayLists and I'm trying to test the the method loadData() has loaded the arrays by making sure that the arrays are not null.
However when I try to get the isEmpty() method for the ArrayList in the fields array I get the error: Cannot resolve method 'isEmpty' in 'Object'
as well as: No candidates found for method call fields[0].get(dataSource).isEmpty()

Do you know how I can get my ArrayLists out of the fields array?

Comment: You have to cast. But before doing that, perhaps spend some time to think about another way to test this or whether this test provides value/benefits. Or maybe redesign your class to be more easily testable

Comment: "Making sure the arrays are not null": rather than making a collection `null` (and causing an NPE later when calling `#isEmpty`), you could just use `Collections#emptyList` as a default value (or initialize your lists).